# Printing a 2D-array

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I am creating an exe file for a school project using python. In this program I am using 2D-arrays for the items in the catalog, so I can have their prices together. When I print the 2D-array the [] and the "" are also showing, how can I print them without showing?

This is my code:

```
coffee_m = ["Espresso", 1.80,], [ "Cappuccino", 1.80], ["Greek", 1.50]
```

This is a very simple version of the lists I have in my actual code

Comment: How are you actually printing?

Answer (score 0):

You might use `for` loop with unpacking

```
coffee_m = ["Espresso", 1.80,], [ "Cappuccino", 1.80], ["Greek", 1.50]
for name, price in coffee_m:
    print(name, price)
```

output

```
Espresso 1.8
Cappuccino 1.8
Greek 1.5
```

observe that name and price are `,`-sheared and can be accessed like in for loop with single variable in flat list.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution can be

```
coffee_m = ["Espresso", 1.80,], [ "Cappuccino", 1.80], ["Greek", 1.50]

for coffee in coffee_m:
   print(*coffee)
```

`*` simply unpacks a list and return every element from it.
If you want a seperator you can use

```
print(*coffee, sep=", ")
```